# The command php artisan key:generate cause error when using in Github action CI flow (The laravel version is v9.46.0)

Tags: php, laravel, github-actions

This is the error screenshot when I use GitHub action for CI. It seems something is wrong with the composer autoload file at step "**Generate key**" but I am not sure how to fix it.
[image: sdsdsd]

This error doesn't occur in my local when I follow the same step in github action config file.

This is laravel.yml config for github action

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database
        touch database/database.sqlite
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I try the same config above for another laravel project (v8) and this error doesn't occur

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^3.3",
        "fico7489/laravel-pivot": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^9.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.10",
        "predis/predis": "^2.0",
        "stevebauman/purify": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.7",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.14",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "pestphp/pest": "^1.22",
        "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^1.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "Tests\\Utility\\function.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you given the permission of 775 to you vendor directory of your project?

Comment: It seems to be trying to open `"Tests\\Utility\\function.php"` (which is in your autoload-dev) and it can't find it. Double check the file is there (i.e. you didn't forget to commit it or something)

Comment: @BhattAkshay yes, i give the permission already

Comment: @apokryfos, This file already exists in the source code, when I try to rename the path 
"Tests\\Utility\\function.php" to "tests\\Utility\\function.php", (with T uppercase to t lower case) the error doesn't occur again. Thank you

Comment: @huyleuit please run this command once ==> `composer dump-autoload` and than check again

Comment: Ok so safe to assume you develop on windows (case insensitive filesystem) and are deploying on Linux (case sensitive filesystem)